# Regex that matches only one occurrence

Tags: java, regex

I'm wanting to replace all occurrences of "=" with "==" in a string with a Regex, but only where there is a single occurrence of "=".

Basically I want to transform:

```
where a = b | c == d
```

into

```
where a == b | c == d
```

What I'm struggling with is finding just the one occurrence. I've tried `[^=]=[^=]`, but that is matching the characters on either side too.

Comment: Have you considered using a full AST parser?

Comment: @Antimony - I actually have, because I need to validate more than just this simple = case. I've looked at the Closure compiler and parboiled, but they feel like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Do you have any simpler suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!=)=(?!=)
```

---

Using your example:

```
System.out.println("where a = b | c == d".replaceAll("(?<!=)=(?!=)", "=="));
```

```
where a == b | c == d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[^=](=)[^=]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/5-qCPhMt6_RVO7bi)

Just use capture groups and select them that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the case where there is a space on both sides. `" = " becomes " == "`

```
String str = input.replace(" = ", " == ");
```

*Edit*

If you are looking for situations where `a=6` is present and want to make it `a==6` and you cannot take advantage of targeting the spaces, you may try

```
[\w ](=)[\w ]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/IRhFHZRrJMHtnT6G)

Comment: But he never said the `=`s will be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: @arshajii - It seemed implied from the format in the question.

Comment: @arshajii - See edits for an approach which takes no spaces into consideration.

Comment: It could just as easy be a=b, i.e. no spaces.

Comment: @Kong - That case is handled in the suggestion inside of the edit.